# Can I target a specific Flexbox container and fill it with the contents of another file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am looking for a way to dynamically populate a submenu depending on the selection of the main menu, then, when a user clicks on an item in the submenu, it populates two flexboxes with the contents of another file. I can't figure out how to target a flexbox using JS; or, if that's not possible, what I could do instead. For example:

```
    MENU 1     MENU 2     MENU 3     // user selects menu 2, which populates the submenu from a file
                 ^
    submenu 1 submenu 2 submenu 3    // user selects submenu 3, which populates the flexbox containers
```

FLEXBOX CONTAINERS:

```
------------------------  -----------------------------------------
| SUBMENU 3 HTML PAGE  |  |        SUBMENU 3 HTML PAGE            |
|                      |  |                                       |
|                      |  |                                       |
|   has options that   |  |       dynamically populates           |
|  affect the contents |  |      based on the options selected    |
|   of the other box   |  |       in the other box                |
|                      |  |                                       |
------------------------  -----------------------------------------
```

Is this possible? What should I search to figure it out? I have Googled to no avail, I'm not searching for the right phrase. What should I be looking for?

Comment: [Please read why "is this possible" questions need more focus.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation. You add an event listener on each trigger element—in my case, a `button`. When the button is clicked, you target the `.flex` element adjacent to the button and dynamically insert `HTML` content.

```js
const btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'))

const clearContent = () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.flex')).forEach(item => item.innerHTML = '')
}

btns.forEach((btn, index) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearContent();
    btn.parentNode.querySelector('.flex').innerHTML = menuContents[index]
  })
})

const menuContents = [
  '<div>sub 1</div><div>sub 2</div><div>sub 3</div>',
  '<div>sub 4</div><div>sub 5</div><div>sub 6</div>',
  '<div>sub 7</div><div>sub 8</div><div>sub 9</div>'
]
```

```css
.flex {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 1.5rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  column-gap: 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.flex:empty {
  display: none;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <button>
    Menu 1
  </button>
  <div class="flex"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <button>
    Menu 2
  </button>
  <div class="flex"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <button>
    Menu 3
  </button>
  <div class="flex"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5womxt8/19/)